# ExtJS and Zend Framework MVC

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, extjs

Im making a Zend Framework MVC application using the standard Zend MVC structure and I wanted to know where I should be putting my client-side ExtJS javascript, not the library but my js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Zend Framework MVC layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html)

The suggested Zend Framework module file structure layout

```
docroot/
    index.php
application/
    default/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            FooController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                foo/
            helpers/
            filters/
    blog/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
            helpers/
            filters/
    news/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            ListController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                list/
            helpers/
            filters/
```

Client side images, javascript, flash, etc should be left within the doc root folder.  The reason behind this is because you should not be passing images/javascript/etc through your bootstrap.  Doing that adds increased server side processing and lengths load times.

To follow the module layout of this example something like this works well.

```
docroot/
    default/
        images/
        js/
        css/
        etc/
    blog/
        images/
        js/
        css/
        etc/
    news/
        images/
        js/
        css/
        etc/
    index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Like all your static files, in public folder.

Comment: I use Kohana, and I create folders at the root level for css/js/imgs. Your framework doesn't need to know about them

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Zend(1.11) has a suggested site layout as per:

```
{project}/
    application/
        configs/
            application.ini
        modules/
            {news}/                # example module
                controllers/
                models/
                views/
        Bootstrap.php
    library/
    public/
        index.php
        { All other public files also go here. eg: }
        js/
            jquery library
            extjs library
            prototype, moo, etc...
        css/
            blueprint
            960
            etc...
        images/
            home.jpg
            etc...
    templates/
```

Essentially any file that needs to be served directly by the webserver and not via the Zend framework, should be placed within your `./{project}/public` directory.